# Angular2 DI error in jasmine test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, dependency-injection, jasmine

I'm writing some angular2 unit tests using jasmine and working on a unit test for a component. For some reason, when I try to instantiate the component using the `TestBed` class, I get a dependency injection error.

`LoginComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    template: require('./login.template.pug'),
    styles: [require('./style.scss')],
    providers: [LoginService]
})
export class LoginComponent {
    public username: string;
    public password: string;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    }

    public login(username, password) {
        this.loginService.login(username, password)
            .then((token: string) => {
            })
    }
}
```

`LoginComponentTest`:

```
import { TestBed, inject, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


describe('LoginComponent', () => {

    class MockClass {
        get(url): Promise<any> {
            throw Error('not implemented');
        };
    }

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                LoginComponent
            ],

            providers: [
                LoginComponent,
                { provide: LoginService, useClass: MockClass },
            ],

            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                BrowserModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule
            ]
        })
    }));


    it('will let user login', async(() => {
        TestBed.compileComponents()
            .then(() => {
                let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
            });
    }));
});
```

The line

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
```

gives the following error:

> Chrome 57.0.2987 (Mac OS X 10.12.3) LoginComponent will let user login
>   FAILED    Error: DI Error
>         at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:958:0 <-
>   config/spec-bundle.js:75553:33)

I have the `LoginComponent` declared along with its own dependency, `LoginService`.

Any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: You've omitted the code for `LoginComponent`.

Comment: I added `LoginComponent` and removed all the unnecessary dependencies  so it's simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, kind of. Apparently the issue has to do with the `providers` declaration in `LoginComponent`:

```
providers: [LoginService]
```

Once I moved that out of `LoginComponent` and into `AppModule`, things started working. Would be interested to know why the test doesn't work with it declared inside the component itself.

Comment: I think since angular 2 rc5 or rc6, `providers` is moved into `module.ts`. It seems it still works inside the component declaration, but maybe testbed is checking at module level?!